How to send information from Zoho Catalyst to Zoho CRM?
I need to send information from Zoho Catalyst to Zoho CRM. How to hit the Zoho CRM API from Catalyst functions? I am struck with authenticating the Zoho CRM API from Catalyst to maintain the sync.
I am sure someone might have tried the integration from Catalyst to CRM.
Any thoughts on this?

You can use the Zoho CRM Rest API from your Catalyst function to send data from Zoho Catalyst to Zoho CRM. You can create an API client from the Zoho API console with Client type as Server Based Application (if you want to build an application for different users) and generate a refresh token for the same on behalf of the users from your Catalyst function. You can find the API documentation for the Zoho CRM API here.
Once you have obtained the refresh token you can use the Catalyst connectors to automatically generate generate access token which you can use to access Zoho CRM. You can find the help documentation for Catalyst connectors here.
You can also try their Zoho CRM Lead Manager tutorial which illustrates the integration of CRM's Lead module directly from a Zoho Catalyst application. It has the step by step guidance with code samples in Java, NodeJS and Python.
